# Trying to merge & create a synonym for tags results in "Oops! Something bad has happened!" Error

Tags: bug, tag-synonyms

I'm tryign to create a synonym & merge [word-2011](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/word-2011) & [microsoft-word-2011](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word-2011) with  [microsoft-word-2011](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word-2011) set as the master tag.

Trying to do this results in

> Oops! Something Bad Happened!

error. The error page doesn't seem to have actual error message as HTML comment anymore, so that's all I can give.

This is the link which causes the problem.

https://superuser.com/admin/merge-tags?preview=true&mastertag=microsoft-word-2011%20&removetag=word-2011&ensuresynonym=True

Comment: You mean you want to reverse the current synonym that maps **microsoft-word-2011** to **word-2011**

Comment: There is already a synonym microsoft-word-2011 -> word-2011 http://superuser.com/tags/word-2011/synonyms

Comment: @Braiam wasn't so when when the error was raised.

Comment: @random yeah, but that wasn't the case when the error was raised, the synoym wasn't present

Comment: Well that seems mischievous of the system to synonymise like that

Comment: @random ok, to clarify, I did create the synoynm but failed to merge - look at my answer below

Answer (score 1):

The general flow I follow when merging tags is

- Propose a synonym from the individual tag page
- [Approve it from tag synonyms](https://superuser.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=newest)
- Merge the questions from both the tags [using the merge option](https://superuser.com/tags/synonyms?filter=merge&tab=newest)

When following the same for the above tag, I ran into the above error. I went over to the [tag synonym page](https://superuser.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=newest), swapped the mapping & proceeded with the merge, at which point it went fine.

Still curious to know about the error